# Why use Core Api of dropbox as opposed to Sync API

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to use dropbox to put the .db file on the cloud and retrieve it back. I searched SO and all I found was examples of RESTFUL calls using the Core API of dropBox.

However I find that Sync Api is easier to use but no examples of using it for this purpose. Any reason why or why I should go with the Core API as oppose to the Sync Api?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Core API is designed to work with server-side apps. The Sync API is specifically designed to work with mobile clients, has SDK's for iOS and Android and is much simpler and easier to use.

Sync API's do not support the more advanced features of Core API's such as full permissions, file revisions etc. But for simple file syncing and retrieval purpose like yours, Sync API's are perfect.

Comment: Can I upload files from FileInputStream source with sync API or need to use Core API?